# Real VNC 4.x gets upgraded automatically to 5.x

Tags: realvnc

I am using Real VNC version 4.x on my test automation machines. this is a free version.

On 2 of those machines the vnc gets upgraded automatically to 5.x and asks for a license key

I have been un-installing 5.x on those machines and installing the older version till this time

Can someone help me understand why is the upgrade happening and is there a way to stop it?

( Note : I have tried other VNC products like Tighe VNC and Ultra VNC and i think Real VNC gives me a better performance and i would like to stick with it)

Answer (score 0):

Unless someone is pushing out updates via something like Group Policy there is no way version 4.x will automatically upgrade itself to 5.x. Your system admin might know the answer to this.